# Disable scroll area in QTableView/QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, tableview

I currently have a QTableWidget into a QScrollArea and I would like to trigger the scrollbar of my scroll area when it's needed instead of the one on the TableView.
I managed to disable the scrollbar of the TableView but the other one is not triggered.

```
    auto *scroll = new QScrollArea;
    auto *scrollWidget = new QWidget;
    auto *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(scrollWidget);

    auto *table = new QTableWidget;

    table->setRowCount(3);
    table->setColumnCount(4);

    // Disable scroll bar of the table
    table->horizontalScrollBar()->setDisabled(true);
    table->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    gridLayout->addWidget(table);

    scroll->setWidget(scrollWidget);
    scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scroll->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
```

I think it's about the viewport of the TableView. Maybe the idea is to have the viewport adjusted to the content.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the view's scroll area? That would certainly be the simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed setting the fixedWidth of the table like this :

```
int size{ 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < table->columnCount(); ++i)
    size += table->columnWidth(i);

table->setFixedWidth(size);
```